# Copy constructor in c++ with overloading operator ()

Tags: c++, constructor, operator-overloading

I try to write a simple code to understand how overloading operators and copy constructor works. But I stacked in one place. Here is my code

```
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;

 class Distance
 {
    private:
       int feet;             
       int inches;           
    public:
       // required constructors
       Distance(){
          feet = 0;
          inches = 0;
       }
       Distance(int f, int i){
          feet = f;
          inches = i;
       }
       Distance(Distance &D){
          cout<<"Copy constructor"<<endl;
          this->feet = D.feet;
          this->inches = D.inches;
       }
       // overload function call
       Distance operator()(int a, int b, int c)
       {
          Distance D;
          // just put random calculation
          D.feet = a + c + 10;
          D.inches = b + c + 100 ;
          return D;
       }

 };
 int main()
 {
    Distance D1(11, 10);
    Distance D2 = D1(10, 10, 10); // invoke operator() why here copy constructor is not called
    return 0;
 }
```

My question is that : Why in this line of main

```
Distance D2 = D1(10, 10, 10); // invoke operator() why here copy constructor is not called
```

Copy constructor is not called. Should not it firstly invoke overloading operator and afterwards go to copy constructor? Why does it give error?

Comment: D2=D1 uses assignment operator. For the operator() NRVO is used so no copy there either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `D2` already exists. You have created it just line above with

```
Distance D1(11, 10), D2;
                     ^
```

So the meaning of the `=` is `operator=`. The object is *assigned* new value ( this new value results from a call to `operator() ( int, int, int)` on `D1`) and not *created* ( constructed) with some value.

To call a copy constructor you need to assign a value to object in the line of its creation

```
int main() {
    Distance D1(11, 10);
    Distance D2( D1);   // calls copy ctor
    Distance D3 = D1;   // calls copy ctor
    return 0;
}
```

but

```
int main() {
    Distance D1(11, 10);
    Distance D2;
    D2 = D1;   // calls operator=
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here:

```
D2 = D1(10, 10, 10);
```

You call the `operator()` in `D1(10, 10, 10)` and then you are calling `operator=`.

If you want to call a copy constructor, you need do the following:

```
Distance D2(D1);
```

Just a tip: take a look on the copy constructor signature - it shows exactly how you should call it.

Comment: Although if you do `Distance D2 = D1`, it will also copy-construct `D2`.